# Find the sum of each label in each cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I've got a UITableView with 3 labels in each cell; Activity name, duration and met. Values are taken from user input, stored in the activities array and then displayed in the table. What I'm not sure how to do is sum the value of the 'met' value in each cell and display that sum in another label outside of the tableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellReuseIdentifier = @"CellReuseIdentifier";
    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TestCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
    }

    MyActivity *activity=(MyActivity *)[self.activities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Activity Name: %@",activity.description];

    NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Activity Duration: %d minutes",activity.duration];

    NSString *met = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your MET: %d minutes",activity.duration* activity.intensity];

    cell.activityLabel.text = name;
    cell.durationLabel.text = value;
    cell.metLabel.text = met;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: just loop through your activities array?

Answer (score 1):

Cell are used for presentation only, you can not take the data from the cells. I would suggest that you write a function that will iterate through your array to sum up everything and update the label which is outside of table view.

You can write a custom reload method like that :

```
-(void)computeAndReloadData
{
    [self computeSum];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fast enumerate the array

```
CGFloat metTotal;
for (MyActivity *eachAct in self.activities) {
    CGFloat met = eachAct.duration * eachAct.intensity;
    metTotal = metTotal + met;
}

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",metTotal];
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added it in under my UITableView code, is that correct? It's not returning anything in my label

Comment: no. you can add it in the viewDidLoad after retrieving data

Answer (score 0):

Calculate sum from your array like:

```
-(int)sum
{
    int sum = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < self.activities.count; i++)
    {
      MyActivity *activity=(MyActivity *)[self.activities objectAtIndex:i];
    sum += [activity.duration intValue];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        
{

        double totalMet = 0.0f;

        for (MyActivity* aActitivity in activities) {

            totalMet = totalMet + (activity.duration* activity.intensity);

        }
        outsideLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",totalMet];

    return [activities count];
  }
```

Comment: Any specific reason for including sum logic in `numberOfRows` ?

Comment: Whenever you reload the data it will update the outside label as well. No need to have seperate function and call on each reload data.:)

Comment: Its giving me 'use of undeclared identifier 'activity'' and that the local declaration of totalMet hides instance variable

Comment: Aha, sorry didn't read the aActitivity typo! Thanks great help!

Comment: Just another quick question. Should 'if (metValue >= 450)' work in the same method? Can't even get NSLog output